# Android PrintService display toast

Tags: android, printing, android-toast

I have an android PrintService launched by an Application.
I would like to be able to display toasts from the PrintService when I'm selecting the printer on which to print etc. (UI generated by the android system, [picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6Myy.png)).

On Android <11 it works fine, however for 11+, I'm not able to display a toast...
I've tried several code (Kotlin) :

```
Toast.makeText(<context>, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

```
Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
    Toast.makeText(context.applicationContext, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
```

Where I tried the following values of  :

- this (the PrintService)
- this.applicationContext
- this.baseContext

Still, I'm never able to display a toast on the printer selection page...
Is it possible ? What is wrong in my code ?